# Google Calendar: Recurring Event Every X WEEKdays?

Tags: google-calendar

I need to create a Google Calendar event that repeats every 3 days, but NOT counting weekends.  For example: Mon, Thu, Tue, Fri, Wed, Mon, Thu, etc.

I know how to do a "repeat every X days" but it includes weekends.

Is there a way to exclude weekends?

Comment: This should additionally be a feature request for Google.

Answer (score 6):

There's no way to do that natively with Google Calendar. There might be a way to do it with ICAL, but you'd need a client that could create the events with the right setup or to build it manually by hand.

Since every three workdays is a repeating cycle...

1. Monday, Thursday
2. Tuesday, Friday
3. Wednesday
4. Monday, Thursday
5. ...

In week 4 the pattern starts again.

One not-too-painful workaround would be to create three separate events, each with the same information.

Here's how you can do that:

1. In week 1, create the event on Monday. Set it to repeat *Weekly*, every **3** weeks, on **Monday** and **Thursday**
2. In week 2, create the event on Tuesday. Copy the information from the event in week 1. Set it to repeat *Weekly*, every **3** weeks, on **Tuesday** and **Friday**
3. In week 3, create the event on Wednesday. Copy the information from the event in week 1. Set it to repeat *Weekly*, every **3** weeks, on **Wednesday**

It's not as simple as a single event, but at least it's only three to manage.

Answer (score 3):

I found a way:

1. Click on the event that you want to reoccur every work day.
2. Click on the "Does not repeat" button then click on **custom**.
3. Set the quanity to **repeat every 1** the go to the other box and click **week**.
4. Click on monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday and friday as the repeating days. (OR which ever days you would like this event to be scheduled).
5. Click Save.

Comment: That's not the solution. That will set the event to repeat every Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, and Friday, which is not what is desired.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question that was asked, however it does answer the question that I asked Google.. Please, take my upvote.

Comment: Upvoted just because this helped me figure out how to do a recurring event on MTWTF, and it was totally unintuitive to try to set it up in the Google Calendars UI after I had initially tried "repeat every 1 day".